# Failed to move to new namespace when open man page in the chromium

Tags: linux, debian, chromium, manpage

I would like to make manpages open in the chromium (from the `man -H` command), but I get this error:

```
yoline@yolinePC:~$ man -H ls
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[2813:2813:0823/005741.984026:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(186)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
#0 0x55eb8a223509 <unknown>
#1 0x55eb8a171cc6 <unknown>
#2 0x55eb8a189cd4 <unknown>
#3 0x55eb8b421f80 <unknown>
#4 0x55eb89c73082 <unknown>
#5 0x55eb8b420c79 <unknown>
#6 0x55eb8b4234a5 <unknown>
#7 0x55eb89c7410a <unknown>
#8 0x55eb89ca1d71 <unknown>
#9 0x55eb89c719a5 <unknown>
#10 0x55eb8761006d ChromeMain
#11 0x7fd0cb19b09b __libc_start_main
#12 0x55eb8760feca _start

Received signal 6
#0 0x55eb8a223509 <unknown>
#1 0x55eb8a171cc6 <unknown>
#2 0x55eb8a221dc3 <unknown>
#3 0x55eb8a223495 <unknown>
#4 0x7fd0d2199730 <unknown>
#5 0x7fd0cb1ae7bb gsignal
#6 0x7fd0cb199535 abort
#7 0x55eb8a223435 <unknown>
#8 0x55eb8a189e98 <unknown>
#9 0x55eb8b421f80 <unknown>
#10 0x55eb89c73082 <unknown>
#11 0x55eb8b420c79 <unknown>
#12 0x55eb8b4234a5 <unknown>
#13 0x55eb89c7410a <unknown>
#14 0x55eb89ca1d71 <unknown>
#15 0x55eb89c719a5 <unknown>
#16 0x55eb8761006d ChromeMain
#17 0x7fd0cb19b09b __libc_start_main
#18 0x55eb8760feca _start
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffc94133af0 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 00007ffc94134d40 r13: 00007ffc94134f00 r14: 00000000000000aa r15: 00007ffc94133d70
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffc94133af0  bp: 00007ffc94133d40  bx: 0000000000000006
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007fd0cb1ae7bb  sp: 00007ffc94133af0
  ip: 00007fd0cb1ae7bb efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
man: couldn't execute any browser from chromium
```

My os is Debian and I use [i3](https://i3wm.org/) as window manager. My English is not very good, but I'm working on it.

---

I solve this problem by using command `export BROWSER="i3-msg exec chromium"` instead of `export BROWSER="chromium"`.

but I get another problem that the chromium did not find the HTML file in `/tmp`.

I can't solve this problem until I see [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/27buyv/i_just_leaned_about_man_html/chzecgt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

1、create a script "open-delay.sh" with the following contents:

```
i3-msg exec xdg-open $1
sleep 5
```

2、invoke man with `man --html=/path/to/open-delay.sh page`, or you can add a alias to `.bashrc` in your home directory with the following contents:

```
alias manhtml="man --html=/path/to/open-delay.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as root? You shouldn't be logged in to a graphical user interface as root and you certainly shouldn't be running a web browser as root at all. Try logging into your system as a regular user.

Comment: no, I am logged into my system as a regular user. I am sorry that my error message was not copied completely (The user name is not copied) and I have modified it.